# Is it possible to move a static method into another class and refactor simultaneously on Visual Studio? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, refactoring

Pardon if this has been answered somewhere before.

I am not entirely sure how to phrase this question, so I'll do an example:

Lets say we have 2 different classes, **A** and **B**. If I have a static method in class **A** that I normally call by using "**A**.*Method*()" in my program, would it be possible to move this method from **A** to **B** so that it automatically refactors this new location "**B**.*Method*()" everywhere in the program?

In short, I would like to refactor the "**location**", rather than the method's "*name*", as I am moving methods from many different classes into one static method library.

Thank you for any pointers you can provide.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible but if you move the method from `A` to `B` and try to rebuild the solution, you'll get a compiler error for each reference of `A.Method()`. If there aren't many references, you can fix them one by one or you can use `Edit > Replace in Files` to replace all occurrences of `A.Method()` to `B.Method()`.

Comment: I don't believe VS can do that, but there's a tool for VS called ReSharper (made by JetBrains) that will do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but if you're sneaky, you can do it this way.

1. Change the name of `B` to `C`. Do not auto-refactor. This will break compilation temporarily.
2. Change the name of `A` to `B`. This time, do allow the auto-refactor. This will change all instances of `A.Method()` to calls to `B.Method()`.
3. Move (copy and paste) the code from `C` back into `B`. This will fix the compilation errors introduced in step 1.

On the other hand, it might be simpler just to use a traditional search and replace (ctrl+F or shift+ctrl+F).

Comment: Your comment about Find and Replace is on point and simple to execute if you have < 20 functions. Write your new class and functions and then start Find/Replace from the old class and namespace.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches that you could consider is to rename the namespace of class A to be class B. Find out what files broke from the change, then do find and replace and this files to switch the using namespace to the one that class B reside.

The refactoring tool like ReSharper might be able to shorten the amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently moving `public static User activeUser = null;` from the class `Interface` to the class `BankManager`. And this is how I do it:

1. CTRL-F for opening the search function.
   You get the following window in the top right(At least I do):

[image]

2. Then press the down arrow:

[image]

3. Then press the other down arrow:

[image]

4. And now select the option "Entire Solution".

[image]

5. In the "Search" box, I write what is currently used to reference `activeUser` from other classes, namely `Interface.activeUser`.

[image]

6. Then in the "Replace" box, I write what will be used.

[image]

7. Then finally, I hit the "replace all" icon.

[image]

8. And now, every other instance of `Interface.activeUser` in the entire solution has changed.
9. If you also referenced the `activeUser` within the `Interface` class, you'll likely need to do the same but instead you'd do:

[image]

After this, at least in my experience it's all done. And sure, there's a lot of little steps. I simply wanted to be very thorough in my explanation. But it only takes about 20-30 seconds at most.

Hope it helps someone!